# Initialize a Ruby class depending on what modules are included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, initialization

I'm wondering what is the best way to initialize a class in ruby depending on modules included. Let me give you an example:

```
class BaseSearch
    def initialize query, options
        @page = options[:page]
        #...
    end
end


class EventSearch < BaseSearch
    include Search::Geolocalisable

    def initialize query, options
    end
end

class GroupSearch < BaseSearch
    include Search::Geolocalisable

    def initialize query, options
    end
end

module Search::Geolocalisable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        attr_accessor :where, :user_location #...
    end
end
```

What I don't want, is having to initialize the :where and :user_location variables on each class that include the `geolocalisable` module.

Currently, I just define methods like `def geolocalisable?; true; end` in my modules, and then, I initialize these attributes (added by the module) in the base class:

```
class BaseSearch
    def initialize query, options
        @page = options[:page]
        #...
        if geolocalisable?
            @where = query[:where]
        end
    end
end

class EventSearch < BaseSearch
    #...
    def initialize query, options
       #...
       super query, options
    end
end
```

Is there better solutions? I hope so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not override `initialize` in the module? You could do

```
class BaseSearch
  def initialize query
    puts "base initialize"
  end
end

module Geo
  def initialize query
    super
    puts "module initialize"
  end
end

class Subclass < BaseSearch
  include Geo
  def initialize query
    super
    puts "subclass initialize"
  end
end

Subclass.new('foo') #=>
  base initialize
  module initialize
  subclass initialize
```

Obviously this does require everything that includes your modules to have an initialize with a similar signature or weird stuff might happen

Comment: I'll try, but do you know if it works the same way when using ActiveSupport::Concern? In this case, I didn't think that the included module acted almost as a superclass like it does in your example.

Comment: Ok so it works exactly the same, and your solution was what I was looking for, thanks. Random thing I learned while searching: calling `super()` is different from `super`. Logical but still ^^.

Answer (score 0):

See this code :

```
module Search::Geolocalisable
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      attr_accessor :where, :user_location #...
    end
  end
end

class EventSearch < BaseSearch
  include Search::Geolocalisable
end
```

Comment: The problem is not about adding the accessors. ActiveSupport::Concern and `included do; end` takes care of that. It's about finding a good way to initialize them in every class the module is included :)